# Why I can not directly get the content of `.bss` section?

Tags: binary, elf, disassembly

Test is on Linux 32bit.

I use this command to get the context of `.text` `.rodata` and `.data` section:

```
objdump -s -j .text elf_binary
objdump -s -j .rodata elf_binary
objdump -s -j .data elf_binary
```

But basically when I tried to use this to get the content of `.bss` section, I always get the error shown below:

```
objdump -s -j .bss elf_binary

objdump: section '.bss' mentioned in a -j option, but not found in any input file
```

Basically how can I get the content of `.bss` section from ELF binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.bss` section comprises zero-valued data.  Usually, an object file only contains the desired start address and extent of the section, but does not actually reserve space for its bits.

Please see the [Wikipedia article on .bss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) has more information.